# How to edit data sql for Json output

Tags: php

I want to add this `symbol [ ]` to the column `"Post_images"`
with basis data sql server

Like this,

```
“post_images” : “ht tp://img*sample*com/gambar1*jpg”, “ht tp://img*sample*com/gambar2*jpg”
```

to

```
“post_images” : [“ht tp://img*sample*com/gambar1*jpg”, “ht tp://img*sample*com/gambar2*jpg”]
```

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more context to the process. Are you inserting this data into the database? Is this data already in the database? Are these variables, if so how are they stored?

Comment: @Dennis this data already in the database, i want to insert this symbol [ ] to data in colomn "post_images"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In json the [] indicates a set of items.

Assuming you have an array with both strings inside then calling json_encode(array) should add the [ ].

See also this tutorial for more detais.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm

Please do not write json on your own. Use the php functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place array for `post_images`
it mean if you have $data which you `json_encodeing` you should add your post images as sub array not string. Example

```
 $data = array(
     'param1' => "data ...",
     'post_images' => array(
          “ht tp://img*sample*com/gambar1*jpg”,
          “ht tp://img*sample*com/gambar1*jpg”
      );
 );

echo json_encode($data); // will output what you where looking for
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the the following:
'["ht tp://img*sample*com/gambar1*jpg", "ht tp://img*sample*com/gambar2*jpg"]'

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/971279/1